# How to get values custom metadata properties

Tags: java, osgi, aem

I'm trying to get the metadata for an asset in the DAM. However, it seems that the metadata comes back as empty for properties that don't have "dc:" in front of them.

```
Resource rs = getResourceResolver().getResource(fileReference);
Asset asset = rs.adaptTo(Asset.class);
//this works
title = asset.getMetadataValue("dc:title").toString(); 
//this does not work. 
//I have ensured that "mine.title" is a property and has string value assigned to it. 
customTitle = asset.getMetadataValue("mine.title").toString(): 
//this does not work either
customTitle = asset.getMetadata("mine.title").toString():
```

Is there a way to get the value from a custom metadata property?

Comment: In title = asset.getMetadataValue("dc:title").toString(); toString() might be redundant. asset.getMetadataValue() returns a "String" by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets at the end are simple nodes, so to get some property you can do something like this (depending on actual path of variable `fileReference`):

```
Resource metadataResource = rs.getChild("jcr:content/metadata");
ValueMap properties = ResourceUtil.getValueMap(metadataResource);
customTitle = properties.get("mine.title", "defaultValue")
```

Answer (score 0):

"dc:title" comes with a registered namespace "dc" (Dublin Core) whereas "mine.title" does not.

That's the reason of `title = asset.getMetadataValue("dc:title").toString();` giving you proper value than `customTitle = asset.getMetadataValue("mine.title").toString()`

You can attack this problem in many ways.

- Change the property name to "dc:myTitle" and retrieve it in the same way you are retrieving "dc:title" [0]
- You can retrieve the value of "mine.title" in the way Alex has described.

  Resource rs = getResourceResolver().getResource(fileReference + "/jcr:content/metadata");
  ValueMap damAssetValueMap = damResource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);

  String shortName = damAssetValueMap.get("shortName", String.class);
- Register a new namespace and define options (in your case , its "mine").
  A look at `"/libs/dam/nodetypes"` and `"/libs/dam/options/metadata"` might be helpful.

[0] Check `"/libs/dam/options/metadata"`